# How to execute Batch Apex form Visualforce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

I have three batch classes, I want to execute all three batch classes through button click using visualforce page at the same time.

```
   `LoanofficerBatch lob = new 
    LoanofficerBatch(); 
    database.executebatch(lob);

    RealtorBatch rb = new RealtorBatch(); 
    database.executebatch(rb);

    BuilderBatch bb = new BuilderBatch(); 
    database.executebatch(bb);`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use an apex:commandButton for this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!executeBatches}" value="Run" />
```

Which you'd write a corresponding method for:

```
public void executeBatches() {
    database.executebatch(new LoanofficerBatch());
    database.executebatch(new RealtorBatch());
    database.executebatch(new BuilderBatch());`
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this does not guarantee the batches will execute concurrently (you cannot guarantee this) and depending on how full the flex queue is one or more of the batches could even fail to be queued up.